# Passing a class as an argument, but still use the dot operator?

Tags: c++

There is a lot of rather complicated background to this question which would take a long time to explain... So I'm simplifying drastically and omitting a lot of detail...

Essentially I have a function in which I have an instance of a class. The Class type is Mat and the instance is "Fred". So I can access data within the Fred class with the dot (.) operator, i.e. Fred.data. I'd now like to call a second function in which I wish to do some processing of Fred. If I pass a pointer to Fred, then the second function will have to access its data with the arrow operator (->).

What I am wondering is whether or not I could have passed Fred in a different way such that the code inside function2 could have accessed the data with Jim.data?

```
void function1()
{
  // some code here involving Fred

  int x = Fred.data;

  function2(&Fred)
}
void function2(Mat *Jim)
{ 
  int y = Jim->data;
}
```

Comment: Pass a copy or reference?

Comment: Don't omit; _abstract_. Present your _[testcase](http://sscce.org)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass by reference instead of by pointer:

```
void function1()
{
    // some code here involving Fred

    int x = Fred.data;

    function2(Fred)
}

void function2(Mat &Jim)
{
    int y = Jim.data;
}
```

Reference is essentially a constant pointer that points to at most one object, while pointers can be used to traverse arrays of objects.

If all you do is calling methods and accessing fields, then simple change of `*` to `&` and `->` to `.` will be enough. Be aware though that objects might overload `->` operation, which can cause some troubles if you forget to replace all occurences of `->`.

Answer (score 4):

Pass by reference

```
void function2(Mat& Jim)
```

Even though direct access to data members is a bit of a code smell.

Comment: @juanchopanza, well the pointer was to a non-const object, so I just rolled with the punches :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void function1()
{
  // some code here involving Fred

  int x = Fred.data;

  function2(Fred)
}
void function2(Mat& Jim)
{ 
  int y = Jim.data;
}
```